How to freeze 3D camera angle while selecting points in matplotlib
I have the below code that uses the lasso method to select points. I can toggle this on and off by pressing 'Z'. However, when clicking the left mouse button to draw a lasso contour around the points you want to select, you also move the 3D figure camera around, making it super hard to correctly select the points you want. I have spent hours now trying to come up with a way to freeze the camera while drawing, but nothing I have tried works, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import LassoSelector
from matplotlib.path import Path
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class SelectFromCollection3DLasso:
    """
    Lasso selector for a 3D scatter plot.

    Highlights selected points in red and dims others.
    """

    def __init__(self, ax, scatter, alpha_other=0.3):
        self.ax = ax
        self.scatter = scatter
        self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.alpha_other = alpha_other

        # Get 3D positions
        self.xyz = np.array(scatter._offsets3d).T
        self.fc = scatter.get_facecolor()  # Facecolors
        if len(self.fc) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Scatter plot must have facecolors.")
        elif len(self.fc) == 1:
            self.fc = np.tile(self.fc, (len(self.xyz), 1))

        self.ind = set()  # Selected indices (store unique points)
        self.lasso = None
        self.selection_enabled = False  # Toggle selection mode
        self.camera_interaction_disabled = False  # Track if camera interaction is disabled
        self.cid_rotate = None
        self.cid_zoom = None

    def toggle_selection_mode(self):
        """Enable or disable selection mode."""
        self.save_view()  # Save the current view
        self.selection_enabled = not self.selection_enabled

        if self.selection_enabled:
            self.disable_camera_interaction()
            self.lasso = LassoSelector(self.ax.figure.gca(), onselect=self.on_select)
            print("Lasso selection mode enabled. Draw to select points.")
        else:
            if self.lasso is not None:
                self.lasso.disconnect_events()
                self.lasso = None
            self.enable_camera_interaction()
            print("Lasso selection mode disabled.")

        self.restore_view()  # Restore the saved view

    def on_select(self, verts):
        """Handle lasso selection."""
        self.save_view()  # Save the current view

        path = Path(verts)

        # Transform 3D points to 2D
        points_2d = self.project_3d_to_2d(self.xyz)

        # Find points inside the lasso path
        self.ind = set(np.nonzero(path.contains_points(points_2d))[0])

        # Update colors
        self.update_colors()

        self.restore_view()  # Restore the saved view

    def update_colors(self):
        """Update the colors of the scatter plot based on the selection."""
        self.fc[:, -1] = self.alpha_other  # Dim all points
        for idx in self.ind:
            self.fc[idx, -1] = 1  # Highlight selected points
        self.scatter.set_facecolor(self.fc)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def project_3d_to_2d(self, points_3d):
        """
        Project 3D points to 2D display coordinates using matplotlib's transformation matrix.
        """
        # Get the projection matrix for the 3D plot
        trans = self.ax.get_proj()

        # Convert 3D points to 4D homogeneous coordinates
        points_4d = np.column_stack((points_3d, np.ones(points_3d.shape[0])))

        # Apply the projection matrix
        projected = np.dot(points_4d, trans.T)

        # Normalize by w (homogeneous coordinate)
        projected[:, :2] /= projected[:, 3, None]

        # Return only the X, Y screen-space coordinates
        return projected[:, :2]

    def save_view(self):
        """Save the current azimuth and elevation of the 3D view."""
        self.saved_elev = self.ax.elev
        self.saved_azim = self.ax.azim

    def restore_view(self):
        """Restore the saved azimuth and elevation of the 3D view."""
        self.ax.view_init(elev=self.saved_elev, azim=self.saved_azim)

    def disable_camera_interaction(self):
        """Disable mouse interaction for the 3D plot."""
        if not self.camera_interaction_disabled:
            self.camera_interaction_disabled = True
            # Disconnect the rotate and zoom events
            self.cid_rotate = self.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.block_event)
            self.cid_zoom = self.canvas.mpl_connect("scroll_event", self.block_event)

    def enable_camera_interaction(self):
        """Enable mouse interaction for the 3D plot."""
        if self.camera_interaction_disabled:
            self.camera_interaction_disabled = False
            # Reconnect the mouse events that affect camera movement
            if self.cid_rotate is not None:
                self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_rotate)
                self.cid_rotate = None
            if self.cid_zoom is not None:
                self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_zoom)
                self.cid_zoom = None

    def block_event(self, event):
        """Block any event (no-op)."""
        return

    def print_selected_points(self):
        """Print the currently selected points."""
        selected_points = self.xyz[list(self.ind)]
        print("Selected points (3D coordinates):")
        print(selected_points)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create example data
    np.random.seed(42)
    data = np.random.rand(100, 3)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
    scatter = ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2], s=80)

    selector = SelectFromCollection3DLasso(ax, scatter)

    def handle_keypress(event):
        """Handle keypress events to toggle selection mode or print selected points."""
        if event.key == "z":  # Toggle selection mode
            selector.toggle_selection_mode()
        elif event.key == "enter":  # Print selected points
            selector.print_selected_points()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", handle_keypress)
    ax.set_title("Press 'Z' to toggle lasso selection mode, 'Enter' to print selected points.")

    plt.show()

As you can see I have tried to suppress camera movement via
def disable_camera_interaction(self):
    """Disable mouse interaction for the 3D plot."""
    if not self.camera_interaction_disabled:
        self.camera_interaction_disabled = True
        # Disconnect the rotate and zoom events
        self.cid_rotate = self.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.block_event)
        self.cid_zoom = self.canvas.mpl_connect("scroll_event", self.block_event)

def enable_camera_interaction(self):
    """Enable mouse interaction for the 3D plot."""
    if self.camera_interaction_disabled:
        self.camera_interaction_disabled = False
        # Reconnect the mouse events that affect camera movement
        if self.cid_rotate is not None:
            self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_rotate)
            self.cid_rotate = None
        if self.cid_zoom is not None:
            self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid_zoom)
            self.cid_zoom = None

But it still doesn't work...
